# Why / where does Object.clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException if instance does not implement Cloneable

Tags: java

I came across following statements from java official docs:

> **In `Cloneable`**<sup>[[ref]](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html)</sup>
>
> - A class implements the Cloneable interface to indicate to the `Object.clone()` method that it is legal for that method to make a field-for-field copy of instances of that class.
> - Invoking Object's clone method on an instance that does not implement the `Cloneable` interface results in the exception `CloneNotSupportedException` being thrown.
> - Note that this interface does not contain the `clone` method. Therefore, it is not possible to clone an object merely by virtue of the fact that it implements this interface.

So, I was guessing how `Object` might be checking whether the instance implements `Cloneable` or not and throwing `CloneNotSupportedException`. So, I checked the implementation of `clone()` in java source, and it contains [native declaration](https://github.com/bpupadhyaya/openjdk-8/blob/master/jdk/src/share/classes/java/lang/Object.java#L212):

```
protected native Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException;
```

When I checked java_lang_Object.c for native implementation, I found [this](https://github.com/cscott/Harpoon/blob/master/Runtime/src/sunjdk/java.lang/java_lang_Object.c#L39):

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_java_lang_Object_clone
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    struct claz *claz = FNI_CLAZ(FNI_UNWRAP_MASKED(obj));
    uint32_t size = claz->size;
    assert(claz->component_claz==NULL/* not an array*/);
    return fni_object_cloneHelper(env, obj, size);
}
```

So, I am not finding what makes `Object.clone()` to throw `CloneNotSupportedException` if the instance does not implement `Cloneable`. To be precise, which line of code throws `CloneNotSupportedException`? I am missing something stupid?

Comment: You can't call the method you're pointed, as it's protected. You may override the method in your class

Comment: Yes but we dont have to throw the exception ourselves if the class does not implement `Cloneable`. So what (from where) does the exception is thrown?

Comment: Yes it seems. [Line 566](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-hotspot/blob/50bdefc3afe944ca74c3093e7448d6b889cd20d1/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp#L566) is responsible for throwing `CloneNotSupportedException`, right?